# Dart - Como rodar código síncrono de maneira assíncrona?

Tags: flutter, dart

Há alguma maneira no Dart de executar uma função síncrona como se fosse assíncrona? Considere o código abaixo:

```
Future<void> teste() async{
  print("começando...");
  await minhaFuncaoSincrona();
  print("terminou...");
}

void main(List<String> arguments) async{

  teste();

  print("tô aqui");

}
```

Acima,tenho a função minhaFuncaoSincrona() que é uma função síncrona comum, que faz alguma tarefa tipo consultar um banco de dados e guardar os dados num arquivo, por exemplo. Mas ela é síncrona. Então quando executo o código acima, aparece "começando..." mas só depois de alguns instantes, após função minhaFuncaoSincrona() ser concluída, aparece "tô aqui". Diferente se minha função fosse assíncrona, pois dai apareceria "começando..." e imediatamente já apareceria "tô aqui", pra só depois voltar pra dentro da função teste().
Em Python, por exemplo, eu tenho a função event_loop.run_in_executor(), onde passo minha função síncrona como parâmetro e ele a executa de forma assíncrona. Existe algo parecido no Dart, que me permita pegar uma função síncrona e executa-la como se fosse assincrona?

Comment: Fala Paulo. Não sei se entendi muito bem sua pergunta. Se a função síncrona realmente é síncrona, porque você precisa aguardar (```await```) ela? Os exemplos que você deu, consultar banco de dados ou salvar dados em um arquivo são normalmente assíncronos. Se ela é realmente síncrona o comportamento que você citou não deveria acontecer. Não entendo muito bem a razão para você querer isso. Mas de qualquer forma, você pode colocar dentro da sua função síncrona, (agora assíncrona com) essa linha: ```await Future.delayed(const Duration(), () {});```. Isso te dá o comportamento desejado?

Comment: Naslausky, vou dar um exemplo mais simples... ali dentro da minha função main, se eu colocar apenas o Future.delayed() que você citou e abaixo um print qualquer, assim que eu executar, o print será mostrado imediatamente. Já se eu substituir o Future.delayed() por um sleep() e executar, ele vai parar no sleep, e só depois vai dar o print. Estou começando dart agora mas imagino que assim como o sleep() haverá outras funçoes sincronas na linguagem que eu vou querer rodar de forma assincrona, por isso já perguntei. Ou no dart tudo já é por padrão assincrono e eu não percebi ainda?

Comment: Perdão se não expliquei direito, Paulo. Minha sugestão foi colocar o Future **dentro** da ```minhaFuncaoSincrona```. E não dentro da ```main```. Mas mesmo com os pontos que você falou eu ainda não sei se entendi muito bem. Talvez se você explicar porque você deseja transformar ela em assíncrona, talvez exista outra forma mais correta de alcançar o resultado desejado.

Comment: Naslausky, sou novo no Dart e depois de olhar mais a fundo, notei que minha dúvida talvez foi infundada. Acontece que em linguagens mais antigas, tipo python ou PHP, muitas funções antigas são bloqueantes (síncronas) mas tem um recurso pra faze-las rodar de forma assíncrona.
Porém no Dart agora vejo que praticamente todas as funções já vem assíncronas. Ou seja, no Dart não tem o problema que eu tenho no Python ou no PHP, de ter um grande legado de bibliotecas e funções que não são assíncronas.